# How to dynamically generate id in dataTable using ui:repeat tag

Tags: jsf-2, el

I am using ui:repeat tag which render images. I have five images i want that on each iteration my image get ids like image1, image2, image3.... imagen. I tried this but it is not working.

```
<div id="imageGallery">
    <ui:repeat value="#{countryPages_Setup.images}" var="image" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void()" class="launchLink">
                    <p:graphicImage id="image#{status.index}"         //problem
                                    value="/resources/images/#{image}"
                                    width="100"
                                    height="100"
                                    rendered="#{countryPages_Setup.renderImages}"/>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
</div>
```

I also tried {staus.index + 1}. I also tried id= image#{1++} But it is also not working. How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use el expressions within the `id` attribute. It needs to be static. The `ui:repeat` itself generates a prefix to your id. You don't need to care about uniqueness.

So, for instance if you have an `id="image"`, then the generated ids are

`somePrefix:0:image`, `somePrefix:1:image`, ...

Comment: yes i saw it in the firebug. Can i append the id 0,1 with the image. Like it become image0, image1? By any means . If it is not possible with the jsf then with jQuery... Actually i want that when one of my image get click then i get the id attribute of the form image1, image2. Here index starts from 0. But i want index stars from 1. Like if image somePrefix:0:image is clicked then i get the id image1, Actually i am using image Gallery in which i need key of the form image1, image2. Thanks

Comment: Of course you could write a jQuery onclick handler that builds the required string.

Comment: Hhmm ok i just want to make sure that it is not possible on JSF side, like using el. Thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

You can use EL in the `id` attribute, but it has to be available during view build time. The `<ui:repeat>` however runs during view render time, it will reuse the same `<p:graphicImage>` to generate multiple HTML `<img>` elements. It doesn't run during view build time, so the `id` remains `image`.

If you replace `<ui:repeat>` by `<c:forEach>`, then it'll work as you intented. The `<c:forEach>` runs during view build time and it will generate multiple `<p:graphicImage>` components which will then each get rendered only once.

```
<div id="imageGallery">
    <c:forEach items="#{countryPages_Setup.images}" var="image" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void()" class="launchLink">
                    <p:graphicImage id="image#{status.index}"
                                    name="images/#{image}"
                                    width="100"
                                    height="100"
                                    rendered="#{countryPages_Setup.renderImages}"/>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

But you can use variable in Javascript, for example:

```
<h:graphicImage ... onclick="top.location.href='http://blabla.com/imageclicked?id=#{status.index}'"/>
```

You can also use Variables with event handlers (since JSF 2.0):

```
<h:commandLink ... action="#{myBean.imageClicked(status.index)"/>
```

But your loop with `c:forEach` can cause problems. Be aware that the JSTL tags (everything that begins with `c:`) are not fully compatible to JSF. If you have luck, then they work as expected. But anyways the slow down the rendering engine, since the page gets processed multiple times by the JSF and JSP rendering engine.

Better use `ui:repeat`.

Answer (score -1):

Just change `<ui:repeat>` to `<c:forEach>`